# socket.io-stream implementation for c++

Tags: c++, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently developing an audio stream server using socket.io and nodejs.
The nodejs client side implementation is easy using socket.io-stream but 
the problem is that now I have a device client that I can only program in cpp

I tried using socket.io client and its working for text and json files but I don't have any idea on how to start sending data stream on the cpp client. Is it possible or should I just switch to web socket for audio streaming using cpp